# How to press 'Home' button on real android device

Tags: java, selenium, appium, appium-android

I'm writing some QA tests for android and faced with an issue that none of the known methods for pressing 'Home' button work. I want to mention that I use `AppiumDriver`, not `AndroidDriver`.

`((AndroidDriver) driver).pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.HOME);` - this one doesn't work
`driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.HOME);` - doesn't work either

Is there any method to press android button in 2020?

Comment: May I know use case? How long you want to keep app in background? meanwhile you want to perform some action when app is in background?

Comment: I need to keep app in background and checking "Home" page untill notification will be shown(2-5 min). The only way to do this what I know - its use AndroidDriver. But I hope there is way to do this with AppiumDriver as well

Comment: https://appium.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/commands/device/app/background-app/   is this solve your problem but you have to tell time to keep app in background. You can use it  like :  driver.runAppInBackground(Duration.ofSeconds(10));

Comment: Am I able to check smth on screen while app run in background by this method?
Im tried to execute this method in another thread but it looks like the driver is fully loaded by executing your method

Comment: I can understand, you will get not driver instance free till app in background. I one solutionbut can you try this first. driver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.HOME));

Comment: Yes its working solution, but only with AndroidDriver. AppiumDriver doesnt have such method

Comment: Intead of going to backgound, you direct can launch that app you want want to switch on with : driver.startActivity(new Activity("com.example", "ActivityName"));

Check here -->  http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/activity/start-activity/

Comment: Thanks, I will check it

Comment: If it will solve your problem then let me know.

Answer (score -1):

Well if you want to send an app in background then simply use

```
`driver.CloseApp()`
```

function and relaunch it by

```
driver.OpenApp()
```

You can also use press keycode method Below are the codes

```
Home Menu Button - 82
Back Button - 4
Recent app - 187
```

Comment: driver.closeApp() is not suitable, since the application is executed differently if the closeApp() is executed and the 'Home' button is pressed.
As I see keycode method is not avaliable for AppiumDriver, only for AndroidDriver, isnt it?